# how to add custom typescript file in fireloop

Tags: fireloop

How to add custsom typescript files in fireloop serve.

for example: i want to add some custom ts file in other folder and want to import into server.js

but it is not possible to import statement in server.js

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I get your question right. If you want to insert custom scripts that are executed when the fireloop server is being started, you should insert those into **/server/boot/your-script.ts**.

If you mean creating custom scripts (remote methods) for specific models, you would have to add them to the specific model typescript file **/server/common/models/your-model.ts**.
You can call the custom remote methods from within your front-end.